# How to set first value default checked for lightning-radio-group

Tags: lightning-radiogroup

Below is the html code

```
<lightning-radio-group name="radioGroup" label="Options" options={options}
onchange={handleChange}></lightning-radio-group>
```

JS

```
  options = [
    { label: 'ECO', value: 'ECO' },
    { label: 'Normal', value: 'Normal' },
    { label: 'Sport', value: 'Sport' },
   ];
```

ECO radio option should be checked bydefault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via the documentation found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-radio-group/specification), in your javascript do this, set the value and use this value in your lighting-radio-group. I have edited the code for you, please find it below.

JS

```
value = 'ECO';
options = [
{ label: 'ECO', value: 'ECO' },
{ label: 'Normal', value: 'Normal' },
{ label: 'Sport', value: 'Sport' },
];
```

HTML

```
<lightning-radio-group name="radioGroup" label="Options" options={options}
onchange={handleChange} value={value}></lightning-radio-group>
```

Hope it helps!